# Javascript JSON array gives no result

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some code that I want to change because the keys are not always named the same.

But when I change it to key numbers it won't work anymore.

This is my object:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1622844000,
  "datetime": "2021-06-05 00:00:00",
  "COMBINED COUNT": [ -3, 0, 3, -109 ]
}
```

This is the code that i use to read the data and put it in some google chart afterwards:

```
success: function(obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {                        
    var temp = [JSON.stringify(obj[i]["datetime"]).substr(11,6) , Number(JSON.stringify(obj[i]["COMBINED COUNT"][0])) , "blue"];
    chartdata.push(temp);
  }
```

Gives result:

```
00:00,-3,blue,
```

But now when i change datetime to 1 and COMBINED COUNT to 2 it won't give any result anymore.

```
success: function(obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {                        
    var temp = [JSON.stringify(obj[i][1]).substr(11,6) , Number(JSON.stringify(obj[i][2][0])) , "blue"];
    chartdata.push(temp);
  }
```

Anyone can tell me why this is happening?? And what i have to do to access the right key values?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Thanks mplungjan for the edit. My English is not so good. I gonna try and add some stacksnippet later today.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in how you are accessing the property of an object. By looking at the information provided I assume you are having an array of objects.

`obj[i][1]` this will check for an object at `i` index having property `1`, which is not present in the object, but when you try to access it like `obj[i]["datetime"]` you get the result as `datetime` is available, same goes for `COMBINED COUNT`.

Comment: Yes i think thats exactly the problem,  i want to just take the value of the first key in the array. Is that possible? Because combined count can have other name also. (The array of objects is a JSON file that's taken with $.ajax then on success rhe function(obj) follow-up.

Comment: If I understand it correctly and you want to access the first value of `COMBINED COUNT`, then try `obj[i]['COMBINED COUNT'][0]`

Comment: Yes, that is working. But what I try to tell is that I don't know the name 'combined count' , i only know that it is always on the same position in the array/object. So thats why I use obj[i][2][0] < where I mean [2] is 3rd position in the array/object. But that isn't working. So my question is; is there a way to define that fixed position without knowing it's name? Thanks for all the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

After many more searching i found the answer:

Because it's always the first and second key in my object i use this:

```
var key1 = Object.keys(obj[0])[1];
var key2 = Object.keys(obj[0])[2];
var temp = [JSON.stringify(obj[0][key1]).substr(11,6) , Number(JSON.stringify(obj[0][key2][0])) , "blue"];
```

In key1 I get the name of my 1st key in my object.

In key2 I get the name of my 2nd key in my object.

Then i use that key-names in my temp part and it gives me the right output.
So now I can use like every name on my keys and it will give back what I need.